# How to show the name of the data source of the line in Timelion

Tags: elasticsearch, timelion

I have 20+ datasources some are being update regularly and others are not.
I have made a gruesome concatenate copy/paste thing in Excel. So a "for loop" would be nice, but for now I am primarily missing the names.

```
.es(index=US, timefield=timestamp), .es(index=UK, timefield=base_date)
```

Both show up as:

```
q:* > count
q:* > count
```

I thought I could fix it as follows:

```
.es(index=US, timefield=timestamp, q=US), .es(index=UK, timefield=base_date, q=UK)
```

And than I had my coffee...

Primary question: How to add labels to datasources?

Secondary question: Easy way to see what data sources span what amount of time.

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Comment: Top right corner in timelion: Docs. This will show you the list of functions available, the one of interest to you being "label"

Comment: to clarify further based on your first example, this would be something lik `.es(index=US, timefield=timestamp).label(timestamp), .es(index=UK, timefield=base_date).label(base_date)`